# Download Files with Password in Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, download, credentials, invoke-webrequest

I need to download a 51gb zip file from the internet, to open the website you need to enter a password.

I want to do this with a function in PowerShell(PSVersion:5.1.18362.752), but I can't get any further. My function looks like this:

```
 $securepassword = "thepassword"

function Get-Files {
   
    $Properties = @{
        URI        = "https://theurl"
        Credential = $securepassword
    }
    Invoke-WebRequest @Properties -OutFile "C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\Desktop\thefiles.zip"

}
```

Can the parameter Credential only be used for Windows Credential?

Many thanks for the help

Comment: Get-Credential is just asking for string data. You can put whatever you want in it. It's your target that expects a specific format. You can read the help files for further details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are using Credentials wrong. Credentials is not password only. It is username plus password, and they should be instance of [ICredentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.icredentials)

Please note, that credentials can be passed this way ONLY for web pages that request `HTTP 401` authentication. If web page uses form-based authentication, you should process it as non-standard case and credentials will not work, you will need to post data, keep cookies, etc.

```
$localPath = [System.IO.Path]::Combine(
    [System.Environment]::GetFolderPath([System.Environment+SpecialFolder]::DesktopDirectory),
    'OutFileName.zip')

$wc = [System.Net.WebClient]::new()
$wc.Credentials = [System.Net.NetworkCredential]::new($username, $plainTextPassword)
$wc.DownloadFile($uri, $localPath)
$wc.Dispose()
```

Comment: thanks, found a way to downlaod the files with SFTP